# PHP: error : Undefined index : action in

Tags: php

This is the code and the error is  Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\wamp\www\web\calculator.php on line 24

Here is the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckNCq.png)

Comment: can you keep the code instead of this screen shot ?

Comment: Add your code here...

Comment: Don't just post links, add some details about your problem.

Comment: You didn't declared the `$variable` used in line 24 of calculator.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no value for your select(action). So it's posting blank, try to Assign a value attribute to your options

```
<option value="+">+<option>
<option value="-">-<option>
<option value="*">*<option>
<option value="/">/<option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code. Keep in mind you must have to set value of each option .

```
<select name="action">
   <option value="+">+<option>
   <option value="-">-<option>
   <option value="*">*<option>
   <option value="/">/<option>
</select>
```

Also you can refer here for more information [More Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)